# Basic apache server, mapping 127.0.0.1, to 10.0.0.7:8000

Tags: apache, windows-server-2003, localhost, ip

I'm working on this project where the client has a virtual server setup. I installed apache and such and got everything working fine on localhost. But in order for it to show up on the internets, the people that run this virtual server needs me to:

"If you try and reach 10.0.0.7:8000 you do not come to the index page but if you do localhost the index page is shown. You need to configure so that it listens to it´s Local IP 10.0.0.7."

Now I am kinda new to this court (I am just a simple webdev that likes to put everything together localhost and uploads his stuff with regular ftp). I bet the answer is simple, but their hotline is closed because they are accross the atlantic. Can someone tell me how to go round and do this? (I am almost blushing because for my not knowing). The virtual server is running on Windows 2003 OS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should find it relatively easy to do: [Listen Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#listen)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the httpd.conf file in your apache/conf dir and change the port and address in the listen directive as:

Listen 10.0.0.7:8000

Don't forget to restart the service.